# Phonegap WebIntent plugin won't load

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I can't get the WebIntent plugin to load on my Phonegap project.

On adb I get the error:

```
D/CordovaLog(27881): file:///android_asset/www/js/script.js: Line 28 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webintent' of undefined
```

Phonegap version 3.4.0-0.19.13

I am using this plugin that I found on Phonegap Build website: https://github.com/Tunts/WebIntent

The steps I took:

On terminal, ran `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/Tunts/WebIntent`

Confirmed that the plugin was installed with `phonegap plugin list`

In my script.js, I added some sample code from the project:

```
var address = "some place";

window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
    action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
    url: 'geo:0,0?q=' + address},
    function() {},
    function() {alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent')}
);
```

The error is from the above line, `window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({`

The plugin is loaded at res/xml/config.xml, automatically gets added this line:

```
<feature name="WebIntent">
    <param name="android-package" value="net.tunts.webintent.WebIntent" />
</feature>
```

Comment: have you run `phonegap build` since adding the plugin?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Yes, I have run `phonegap run` and `phonegap build` several times.

Comment: and you are calling this function after `deviceready` event has fired?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon That was it, I incorrectly used it in `$(document).ready` Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out. I will add an answer for others that may find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin functions can only be called after the event `deviceready` has triggered. Any calls made to plugins before that will most likely fail. To prevent this, you can format the loading of you app like the following example:

HTML:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

JS:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady,false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    //Code to render your app's main view
    //any inits or plugin setups
    //hide splash screen if using the splash screen plugin
}
```